# Getting time difference in Swift 3

Tags: swift, date, time, calendar, swift3

I was trying to get the time difference of two dates from this [guide](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2015/01/29/how-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-swift-part-two-calculations-with-dates/). I'm not sure what to put in for the `dateComponents` argument. When I directly pass in `[.hour, .minute]`, I get an error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:10:46: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: stopTime!, to: date!)
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

```

I tried to declare it as a constant first but am unsure what the type is. The argument is of type `Set<Calendar.Component>`, but I'm getting an error when I try to say it's of up `Component`, `DateComponent`, or `CalendarComponent`.

````

```
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a "
let time = "12:03 pm"
let stopTime = timeFormatter.date(from: time)

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let components:[DateComponent] = [.hour, .minute]
let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents(components, from: stopTime!, to: date!)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dateComponents(_:from:to:)` method is declared as follows:

```
public func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, 
    from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents
```

The first parameter is of type `Set<Calendar.Components>` but you seem to provide a `[DateComponents]`. That's why you see the error.

Therefore, it should be done this way:

```
let components:[Calendar.Component] = [.hour, .minute]
let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>(components), 
    from: stopTime!, to: date)
```

First, I changed the array's type to be `[Calendar.Component]`. Second, I created a `Set<Calendar.Component>` before passing `components` to the method. Another thing is that you wrote `date!`. The `!` is redundant because `date` already is a non-optional. No need to unwrap!

Alternatively, you can remove the `components` variable entirely!

```
let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], 
    from: stopTime!, to: date)
```

Now it compiles fine!

However, this might not produce your expected result because `timeFormatter.date(from: time)` produces a date in the year 2000. I got this quite dirty solution, but it works anyway:

```
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let time = "08:00 pm"
var stopTime = timeFormatter.date(from: time)

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: stopTime!)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: stopTime!)

stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .year, value: year, of: stopTime!)
stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .month, value: month, of: stopTime!)
stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: day, of: stopTime!)
stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .hour, value: hour, of: stopTime!)
stopTime = calendar.date(bySetting: .minute, value: minute, of: stopTime!)

let timeDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: stopTime!, to: date)
```

Comment: You have no need to create `Set<Calendar.Component>` explicitly. Try replacing `Set<Calendar.Component>(components)` with `[.hour, .minute]` in your code.

Comment: Oh yes! I never knew that `[]` can also denote a `Set`. @OOPer

Comment: Better note that the OP's issue is caused by the `!` in `date!`.

Comment: @OOPer That was so small of an issue that Xcode automatically gave me a "Fix-it" solution. I unconciously clicked on it. That's why I didn't mention it in the answer.

Comment: The code doesn't compile without explicitly declaring `components` as `Set<Calendar.Component>` but thanks Sweeper for pointing that out in your solution!

Comment: For your dirty solution, it resets the time back to 12:00 am. Is there a way to keep the time the same?

Comment: @stumpedOh I didn't realize that! I updated the answer. Have a look!

Comment: @stumped Bear in mind that this only works if the two times you are comparing arein the same day.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let start = Date();
//Your functions..
let end = Date();
print("Time to do something: \(end.timeIntervalSince(start)) seconds");
```